# navigationController.pushViewController doesn't seem to work in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a basic single view application. Using Xcode 11 now. I always build apps programatically because the tutorials I have started with never use the interface builder. For some reason not able to get the pushViewController to work. Seems to work just fine in my other projects built using Xcode 10.

In App Delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.rootViewController = nc

        return true
    }
```

In my viewController

```
@objc func handleChat(){
    print("Chat pressed")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(InboxViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Can you verify the navigationController isn't nil in handleChat() ?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Koen when I press the chat button, it doesn't push the view controller on to the stack. Nothing works. The button works though while testing it with a print statement

Comment: @Mocha HI! I'll do that and update you. Thanks

Comment: And also check if `InputViewController` is not nil.

Comment: @Koen Hi! Will do that but may I ask why we are checking for InputViewController?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `InboxViewController`

Comment: @Koen ok will do that and update you

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate.swift

```
var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
        var Nav: UINavigationController? = nil
        if let VC = VC {
            Nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
        }
        window?.rootViewController = Nav
        return true
    }
```

Remove SceneDelegate.swift

Goto Info.plist

Remove Application Scene Manifest

It's work for me.